# How i can print the row in Python (Sqlite3, Python)

Tags: python, sqlite

Why Python doesn't print the rows it says nothing in the console.

```
def read_from_db():
cur.execute("select * from people where username=:useru1 and password=:userp1", {"useru1": useru1, "userp1": userp1}) 
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row[0])
    print(row[1])

con.commit()
```

read_from_db()

Comment: maybe your query doesn't match and is just empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
def read_from_db():
  cur.execute("select * from people where username=:useru1 and password=:userp1", {"useru1": useru1, "userp1": userp1})   
  for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row[0])
```

Comment: That works but i want to select only the usernames, so row 0

Comment: If usernames is the first column and has value than row[0], should give the result.